# How do I load a saved image using ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, viewdidload

I'm making a painting app, and I currently have the app at a point where it saves drawings, but it still can't load the drawings back into the view once the app has quit or switched views.

I'm saving the image with this:

```
-(IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *saveImage = drawImage.image;

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage)];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

#### Question

How do I load `imageData` into the view? I'm assuming I can do it in `viewDidLoad`. Can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your saving code looks fine.

To read back the image you would do this:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And yes you can do it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear or anywhere it is appropriate, it really depends on the use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This really helps, but I'm getting an issue saying that  UIImage* image is an unused variable, which doesn't make sense, because it's being defining it right there. Do you have any idea what might be wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: unused means you're not actually doing anything with it. It's just a warning letting you know you either forgot to use it or that it's redundant. The equivalent of defining `int myNumber = 5;` and then just never using the variable. Once you actually assign it to something else or do something else with it, that warning will go away.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm still confused. What would I assign that variable to in order to load the saved image?

Comment: You have a `UIImageView` called `drawImage` right? After the code I posted just do `drawImage.image = image;`